How do I set up an email account on a new Mac Mini 2024?
I've been successful moving over all my gmail accounts from my iMac to my new Mac Mini 2024. But I can't get it to accept the custom Bluehost email I use.
Here are the setup steps I took on the Mac Mini:
Mail > Add Account...
Option: Other Mail Account..., continue button
Add a Email Account panel
Name: [short name]
Email Address: [full email given]
Password: [password for Bluehost server], sign in button
[new panel]
Email Address: [inserted from previous screen]
User Name: [sign-in user ID of Bluehost server given]
Password: [password for Bluehost custom email account]
Account Type: IMAP [default option pre-selected]
Incoming Mail Server: [per Bluehost spec]
Outgoing Mail Server: [per Bluehost spec], Sign In button
In red: "Unable to verify account name or password]
Am I misunderstanding something about the steps to be taken?

I assume you are following these instructions? As this seems to be a commercial offering: did you reach out to their support team to check for anything in the logs on their end?

The only settings in the Account setup are the above fields. There is nothing for inserting a port number. I'm using mail.xxx.com, per Bluehost spec, but perhaps I should be using imap.xxx.com. I'll have to try that.

Go to your Bluehost server settings. Check IMAP settings if you need to check or uncheck any box. You may need to accept new setup to a new device.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

"You may need to accept new setup to a new device" is not standard IMAP behavior. Is this something specific to Bluehost?

This advice does not help. The standard Bluehost settings should work for all email accounts.
